# Java SE 8.0 in server application

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee

I'm going to develop a long-term project, which should scan online news sites, crawl them and store their data in my own database for the further business logic. Since the further business logic will be implemented in Java, I consider implementing the crawling/gathering part in Java as well.

As far as I know, if there is a need to implement a webservice in Java that will constantly run on a server, I have to use Java EE instead of Java SE. But the problem is that Java EE is still 7.0 (till 2017) and lacks many great features, which came with the 8.0 release of Java SE.

Is there any way to use Java SE 8.0 features in my Java application, which runs on a server and monitors web pages or I have to use Java EE instead?

Comment: JEE and Java SE are different technologies with different versioning schemes.

Comment: Java EE 7 and Java SE 7 are different things. You can use Java (SE) 8 with Java EE 7 just fine.

Comment: Packaged JEE7 (ver 8 is absent, sholud be 2016) is kind of "umbrella", for programmers comfort (don't belive) and for manegemets, chefies, corporate life, certified installations etc ... Dont be afraid, start in j8 environment. Nobody uses all JEE modules, in Your groving project add required libs and go

Comment: @Kayaman, I'm a little bit confused with the functionality of Java SE vs. EE. For the project, described above (web pages crawling & parsing), can I use the pure Java SE or I have to use Java EE instead?

Comment: When you need stuff supported by JEE containers, you need JEE - if you don't need this, use Java SE.

Comment: JEE have things quite simple and basic (i.e servlet standard and family, in practice nobody feel it is ENTERPRISE technology) to heavy and scritc for the biggest projects. You select (usually small) parts is independent form

Comment: @MikeB. Nothing in your project sounds like you would absolutely need Java EE, but if you believe that in the future you'd want to access the data through a browser and maybe perform operations on it, Java EE might become a viable option. You can still implement your crawler in regular Java first, then later on integrate it to your potential Java EE application if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is

1. You don't have to use Java EE to build a Java service with Web endpoints
2. You don't have to limit yourself to JDK 7 to use JEE 7

Alternatives to JEE for your use cases would include

- [vert.x](http://vertx.io/)  : very fast asynchronous node.js style event loop for Java
- [spring boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) : automagically configures whatever you need from the Spring stack
- [dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/) (Jersey & Jetty microservices)

If you want to make use of Spring with Jersey Rest end points, you could also take a look at [Microserver](https://github.com/aol/micro-server), a library we maintain @ Aol.

All of the options above can deploy and run as a single standalone app (no app server neccessary - if you want to use Tomcat / JBoss etc Spring MVC is anther alternative to JEE).